# run command on and in subfolders which contain files of specific extension

Tags: shell-script, zsh

Good day all,

I'm trying to run commands on subfolders which contain files with specific extension(s). I want to run the commands inside the folders themselves, and have whatever output be generated inside the folders themselves.

Here is an illustration of what I'm trying to accomplish. I have this to start:

```bsh
.
└── folder
    ├── subfolder 1
    │    ├── file.abc
    │    └── file2.abc
    ├── subfolder 2
    │    └── file.xyz
    ├── subfolder 3
    │    └── file.def
    └── subfolder 4
```

I want to find subfolder 1 and 3 in this case, and have commands run inside them, and have the outputs of said commands also be within their respective folders as so

```bsh
.
└── folder
    ├── subfolder 1
    │    ├── file.abc
    │    ├── file.out
    │    ├── file2.abc
    │    ├── file2.out
    │    └── subfolder.out
    ├── subfolder 2
    │    └── file.xyz
    ├── subfolder 3
    │    ├── file.def
    │    ├── file.out
    │    └── subfolder.out
    └── subfolder 4
```

This code works, ran inside `folder`:

```bsh
if ()(($#)) */*.(abc|def|ghi)(NY1-.); then

        for file (*/*.(abc|def|ghi)) command1 $file && command2 ${file} > $file.out && command3 * > subfolder.out
    else echo "No appropriate files found"
fi
```

But when `command3` on `*` or also `*.(abc|def|ghi)` inside the folders to try to generate a single `subfolder.out` per subfolder, I want it to generate a single file inside said folder with the results. What I get is that the file will be generated and overwritten wherever I run the script, and not inside the folder as I want it to. So if I run this script inside the top `folder`, I get this:

```bsh
.
└── folder
    ├── subfolder.out
    ├── subfolder 1
    │    ├── file.abc
    │    ├── file.out
    │    ├── file2.abc
    │    └── file2.out
    ├── subfolder 2
    │    └── file.xyz
    ├── subfolder 3
    │    ├── file.def
    │    └── file.out
    └── subfolder 4
```

I would want it to generate as follows

```bsh
.
└── folder
    ├── subfolder 1
    │    ├── file.abc
    │    ├── file.out
    │    ├── file2.abc
    │    ├── file2.out
    │    └── subfolder.out
    ├── subfolder 2
    │    └── file.xyz
    ├── subfolder 3
    │    ├── file.def
    │    ├── file.out
    │    └── subfolder.out
    └── subfolder 4
```

So to recap: I want to test subfolders for the presence of files with specific extensions, and then I want to run commands inside the folders that have them, and have the generated outputs all be inside the folders in which they were created. I want to run commands on every file of specific extension it finds inside the folder, but also on a wildcard `*.(abc|def|ghi)`. I would want to run command3 on *all* files of whatever extension it finds, rather than on every individual files of whatever extension it finds.

**I'm basically trying to** `cd` **into folders which contain files that are of the right extension, then** `command3 * > subfolder.out` **. The file** `subfolder.out` **has to be created and remain in the correct subfolder.**

How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: on the go comment: check google for if [ -f "$file" ] - checks for file existence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `find` command with the `-execdir` option like this

```
find <directory> -type f -name "*.<extension>" -execdir <command> {} \;
```

This `find` command will search in ***directory*** for all files (*) with extension ***extension*** and it will run ***command*** in the directory where the file (`{}`) is located.

another example:

```
find /home/mike/ -type f -name "*.java" -execdir pwd \;
```

This command above will find all java files in directory `/home/mike/` and it will print out the current working directory (`pwd`) of any of the files found. If you need to run a command on the current file use `{}` as shown in the first example.

So basically this should do for your usecase:

```bsh
$ tree
.
├── subfolder1
│   ├── test2.abc
│   ├── test2.efgs
│   └── test.abc
├── subfolder2
│   └── test.def
└── subfolder3
    └── test.xyz
```

Then run find:

```
find /home/mike/ -type f \( -name "*.abc" -o -name "*.def" -o -name "*.ghi" \) -execdir sh -c "command3 '{}' > subfolder.out" \;
```

This results in:

```bsh
tree
.
├── subfolder1
│   ├── subfolder.out
│   ├── test2.abc
│   ├── test2.efgs
│   └── test.abc
├── subfolder2
│   ├── subfolder.out
│   └── test.def
└── subfolder3
    └── test.xyz
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems to be a more concise way of writing the statement, but the subfolder.out is still generated in the top folder. This looks very nice though. adding `$(pwd)` gives me a zsh error `no such file or dir` and it cuts the top path (which has spaces).

Comment: Please try again I have updated the last command.

Comment: The `{}` part works well for running on the files in the folder, it's just the output location that has to be controlled still. I'm trying to get the output inside the folder it's run, so every qualifying subfolder can have its own subfolder.out.

Comment: Tried it again, and I get a `find: -execdir: no terminating ";" or "+"` error. I'm in zsh if that makes any difference.

Comment: Probably it does make a difference. Unfortunately I do not know about the specifics with `zsh` The last command works for me. Could you by any chance run this on `bash`?

Comment: Sadly same error in bash as well. `find: -execdir: no terminating ";" or "+"`

Comment: Oh I believe I found the mistake. Updated answer again. The last **"** should be after `subfolder.out`

Comment: This works perfectly, with some tiny alterations but those were specifically for `command3`, which turned out to run differently in a script as when invoked manually. But this is the right approach to loop in folders which contain certain files of specific extensions. Thanks again! Much appreciated!